# Determining the population size of a branching process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose that I have the following branching process. Each parent can have up to two children, the number of which is determined by two independent fair coin flips.

I know that this branching process will eventually go extinct, since each parent runs a Binomial trial with parameters $n=2$, $p=0.5$ and hence $np<1$.

I'm interested in finding a probability bound on the size of the population that this branching process produces. For example, a statement of the form: with probability $q$ the population will be at most $N$ before the process dies out.

I would be great if someone could point me to a reference.

Comment: Actually $np = 1$ in your case, so this is a critical rather than a subcritical process.

Answer (score 2):

There can be two interpretations of your question. Under the first, you are interested in the maximal population existing at any given time, i.e., $\max_i Y_i$, where $Y_i$ is the population at time $i$. Under the second, you are interested in what is knows as *total progeny*, which is $\sum_i Y_i$.

[Lindvall](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4615636) showed that for a critical branching process, $n\Pr[M>n] \to r$, where $M = \max_i Y_i$ and $r = Y_0$ is the initial population.

[Dwass](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3212112) showed that for a subcritical or critical branching process, $\Pr[Z=n] = \frac{r}{n} p_{n-r}^{(n)}$, where $Z = \sum_i Y_i$, $r = Y_0$ is the initial population, and $p_{n-r}^{(n)}$ is the probability that $n$ steps of the process applied to a single parent result in $n-r$ offsprings, i.e. the coefficient of $x^{n-r}$ in $P(x)^n$, where $P(x)$ is the generating function of the process (in your case, $P(x) = (1+x)^2/4$).

Comment: I seem to remember that in the critical case $nP(Z>n)$ converges to a finite nonzero limit (whose exact value escapes me at the time but it should be mentioned in the book by Lyons and Peres).